# CrudRepository query with parameter

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, intellij-idea

I would like to know if there is any way to use a parameter from a function I pass to a repository can be used in the @Query.

I would like to sort users by gaming platform so I added the following function to my UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<DbUser, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT * from users WHERE platform = *****parameter here***** ")
    public List<DbUser> findAllByPlatform(String platform);
}
```

Does anybody know if this is possible? If so, how? If not, is there a clean workaround? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My DbUser class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class DbUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int UserId;

    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String UserName;

    @Column(name="email_address")
    private String EmailAddress;

    @Column(name="password_hash")
    private int PasswordHash;

    @Column(name="platform")
    private String Platform;

    @Column(name="platformid")
    private String PlatformID;

    @Convert(converter = StringListConvertor.class)
    private ArrayList<String> Wishlist;

    public DbUser(String userName, String emailAddress, int passwordHash, String platform, String platformID, String newWishlistItem){
        UserName = userName;
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        Platform = platform;
        PlatformID = platformID;
        Wishlist.add(newWishlistItem);
    }

    public DbUser() {

    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return EmailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public int getPasswordHash() {
        return PasswordHash;
    }

    public void setPasswordHash(int passwordHash) {
        PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    }

    public String getPlatform() {
        return Platform;
    }

    public void setPlatform(String platform) {
        Platform = platform;
    }

    public String getPlatformID() {
        return PlatformID;
    }

    public void setPlatformID(String platformID) {
        PlatformID = platformID;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWishlist() {
        return Wishlist;
    }

    public void setWishlist(ArrayList<String> wishlist) {
        Wishlist = wishlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how is that query sorting? Remove the `@Query` and it will already do the query you want.

Comment: @M.Deinum I assume I have to write a custom implementation, as this method is not in the CrudRepository interface

Comment: No, you don't need an implementation. Spring Data will generate the query for you. Maybe do some reading on the frameworks you are using.

Comment: @M.Deinum I get the following error when I try this: ```Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List project.rlstop.Repositories.UserRepository.findAllByPlatform(java.lang.String)! Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [platform] on this ManagedType [project.rlstop.Models.Database.DbUser]```

Comment: Which means there is no property `platform` on your `DbUser` and thus your `@Query` would fail as well. The query you specify is a JPQL **not** a SQL query. So what is the name of the property referring to the `platform` column in the DB.

Comment: @M.Deinum I do have a private field platform in my DbUser class. Does it have to be a property? I was taught that I should make the fields private and add getters and setters for it to be a proper POJO

Comment: Could you please add your `DbUser` class here?

Comment: Please add your `DbUser` class. The field should be private and in theory, you should have an attribute `platform` that way. Unless you made it transient or use property based access instead of field based.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added it to the question

Comment: Your attribute is named `Platform` not `platform`. you aren't following regular java naming conventions, which is why it fails. Rename your fields to lowercase (or actually camel-case) names.

Comment: @M.Deinum I changed it and it doesn't give an error during running the app. However, calling the function results into a 500 internal server error :S

Comment: Update: apparently this was because Spring was conflicted with two methods that both had the path /users/{variable}. I didn't think this would be a problem because one is an integer and one is a string, but it does appear so. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring data, annotate parameter with @Param and supply variable name to be used in query:

```
@Query("SELECT * from users WHERE platform = :pltfrm")
public List<DbUser> findAllByPlatform(@Param("pltfrm") String platform);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
@Query("SELECT * from users WHERE platform = %?1")
```

[spring data jpa documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)